# The fastest algorithm to solve equation with 2 unknown parametrs in c?

Tags: c, algorithm, equation

I am counting the value of possible combinations of x and y. It works but when I put big numbers it takes way too long. Do you have any ideas for better algorithm?

ax + by = c

The input of program is a, b and c, which should be non-negative numbers.
My code looks like this:

```
int combs=0;
for(int x=0; x < c; x++) {
    for(int y=0; y < c; y++) {
        if( (a*x) + (b*y) == c) {
            combs++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are there limits on a, b, and c?

Comment: They have to be bigger or equal to 0, thats all.

Comment: What is the allowable range of `x,y`? Can x or y be negative?

Comment: "a, b and c, which should be non-negative numbers."  is contradicted by "Are there limits on a, b, and c" and "They have to be bigger or equal to 0".  The later allows, `a,b,c` to be 0.  Of course `a=b=c=0` has infinite solutions.  I am confident that you do not want to allow that.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diophantine_equation

Comment: @Petr Konecny "it takes way too long" --> This can be solved without any iterations on `x,y`, yet looks like you have an acceptable solution already - too bad.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A much faster way is to do some math first. `ax+by=c` => `y=(c-ax)/b`

```
int combs=0;
for(int x=0; x < c; x++) {
    int y = (c-a*x)/b;
    if( (a*x) + (b*y) == c)
        combs++;
}
```

Getting rid of that nested loop is the most important detail to improve performance. Another thing you could do is to do as Antti Haapala suggested in comments below and use ax instead of x.

```
int combs=0;
for(int ax=0; ax < c; ax+=a) {
    int y = (c-ax)/b;
    if( (ax) + (b*y) == c)
        combs++;
}
```

Comment: Lazy thinking today, but isn't it enough to check for zero remainder?

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Quite possible. I don't know.

Comment: also you don't need to loop until `c` but `ceil(c / a)`. Or use `ax` as the variable, and increase by `a` :)

Comment: This will counts as  solutions  `y < 0`, yet not `x < 0`.  Suggest `x < c` --> `x < c/a` to prevent that - faster too.